# Web service parameter is null

Tags: java, rest

I'm having a strange problem where data that is send to my web service is null even though the value is there in the http request. Here is the ajax and rest:

```
    $("#updateProfileInfo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var jobb = $("#jobbEditBox").val();
    var bostad = $("#bostadEditBox").val();
    var intressen = $("#intresseEditBox").val();
    alert(jobb);
    alert(bostad);
    alert(intressen);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/fakebook/fakebookrest/UserInfoService/json/edituserprofile",
        data: {
            "jobb" : jobb,
            "bostad" : bostad,
            "intressen" : intressen
        },
        success: function(data){
            var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(jsonData);
        }
    });
});



@POST
@Path("/json/edituserprofile")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean produceJSON(
        @QueryParam("jobb") String rawJobText,
        @QueryParam("bostad") String rawCityText,
        @QueryParam("intressen") String rawIntresseText,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println(rawJobText);
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    System.out.println(""+user.getId());
    if(user != null)
        return userFacade.editProfileInformation(user.getId(), rawJobText, rawCityText, rawIntresseText);
    else
        return false;
}
```

Everthing else is working fine and there are no errors. The callback function is also called. Only problem is that the value of `System.out.println(rawJobText);` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use @FormParam instead of @QueryParam

Comment: Could you explain why please? Ok I saw it now. POST method works only with formparam

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you may not necessarily use @FormParam. What you can do is to go to your firewall and allow connection to the port that the web service is. By allowing the port the firewall no longer blocks access to data. This would work provided you are sure that your web service is accurate. You can use Postman to test your web service and see the values it is supposed to return.